# Modify standard user accessibility preferences from admin account

Tags: macos, permissions, macos-mojave, user-accounts

I have MacOS 10.14 Mojave with several accounts. One is admin account and then several standard user accounts.

I would like to know if it possible to modify in standard user account applications which have accessibility permissions from my admin account.

If it is not possible from admin account, maybe is possible from root account ?

The goal is if install some application which requires accessibility, avoid to display the popup asking for permissions because they have already given.

Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks in advance